# ant -lib parameter not working on Unix

Tags: unix, ant, lib

I'm trying to run an ant script on Linux using ant-contrib.
I specify the jar using ant's -lib parameter, but it doesn't seem to be detected.

This is the warning I get:
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It could not be found.

And the command I run is:
ant -lib ./lib/ant-contrib.jar -f build-master.xml
I also tried specifying the absolute path, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that it was a problem with ant itself. The environment I was using had ant 1.9.2 installed. As soon as I upgraded to 1.9.6, the lib parameter started to work!